# Hyper-v number of Virtual CPU on Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, hyper-v, hyperthreading

VMware world recommends that you only add one Virtual CPU on each Virtual Machine unless that your application requires detect more than one CPU.

Does this recommendation applies on Microsoft Hyper-V world? or if I requires more CPU power on a Virtual machine, should I increase the number of Virtual CPU?

Regards

Comment: As this is not a programming question, it's probably better you ask this question on ServerFault.

Comment: I have been using Hyper-V from couple of years and I am not aware of any such recommendation for Hyper-V VMs. I allocate Virtual Processors (VPs) based on the workload that runs in that VM and other VMs running on the same physical machine. Maximum number of supported VPs per VM is 1024 in Windows Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Also, you can have as many VPs assigned to the VM as there are Logical Processors on the machine, maximum being 1024 in Server 2012 R2.